# How to rename Array string values with their first letter in ES6/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like below:-

`const data = ['Active', 'Pending', 'Terminated'];`

How to rename the array string values with the first letter.
expected result here:-

`const newData = ['A', 'P', 'T']`

**Note: The data array string values will be increase or decrease.**

Comment: What you've tried so far ?

Comment: What does _“The data array string values will be increase or decrease”_ mean? What exactly is increasing or decreasing here? The length? The alphanumerical order? Why does this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to each entry:

```js
const data = ['Active', 'Pending', 'Terminated'];

const newData = data.map(s => s.slice(0, 1));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = ['Active', 'Pending', 'Terminated'];

const newData = data.map(elem => elem[0]);
console.log(newData);
```